# How to make an azure function to read from the dist folder generated by Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an azure function that works great in JS but I've migrated the code to TS. When I run the deployment I do see the dist folder generated by TS, however, if I go to the Azure portal I still see my old JS function but there's no sign of the dist folder. I have confirmed through Kudu that the dist folder exists and it contains the new code.

How can I let know to the Azure function to read from the dist folder?

This is my current folder structure:

```
- Project
  - azure_func
    - main_func_app
      - funcs
        -func_js
           index.js
           my_ref_vals.json
           function.json
        -func_ts
           index.ts
           my_ref_vals.json
           function.json
        -dist
         -func_ts
            index.js
            index.js.map
       package.json
       host.json
       tsconfig.json
```

Contents of the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

Contents of the package.json

```
{
"version": "0.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "watch": "tsc -w",
  "prestart": "npm run build",
  "start": "func host start --typescript",
  "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\"",
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "format": "prettier --write ."
},
"devDependencies":{
  "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
  "@types/node": "16.x",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.31.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
  "eslint": "^8.20.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
}
}
```

Deployment file:

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage for Azure Function
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '14.x'
          displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'mysub-test-group-SPN'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            npm install
            npm run build

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Create artifact'
        inputs: 
           rootFolderOrFile: 'Project/azure_func/main_func_app/funcs'
           includeRootFolder: false
           archiveType: zip
           archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
           replaceExistingArchive: true

      - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        displayName: 'Publish Azure Functions Artifact'
        artifact: functions

      - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
        displayName: 'Deploy Azure Functions'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'mysub-test-group-SPN'
          appType: 'functionApp'
          appName: 'azure_funcs'
          package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/functions/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Please, comment if something isn't clear.

Comment: have you checked the official resource? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-typescript?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbrowser

Comment: Shouldn't the `rootFolderOrFile` under the `ArchiveFiles@2` task be `Project/azure_func/main_func_app`?

In your tsconfig you set `outDir` as "`dist`", not `"Project/azure_func/main_func_app/funcs/dist"`, so your `dist` folder is at the root, not where your folder structure says it is, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed first thing is to check your files are correctly deployed/copied. I am not sure if you say you don't manage to deploy your folder, or if it is from your code that you don't manage to target you folder/files.

I noticed that the root folder may not be targeted the same way, wether you debug your app or if it deployed. Deployed app maintain folder structure, but my local azf did not (maybe be a configuration on my side).

If it is a path issue .. in C# I had to read a file too in my AZF. I made something like that :

```
string templateFileName = "myfile.txt";
string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

// First part of the ternary identify local file when you debug it
// If not, it will into my AZF project under this path ~/Functions/ExportFunction/myfile.txt
string templatePath = File.Exists(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, templateFileName))
                        ? Path.Combine(currentDirectory, templateFileName)
                        : Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "Functions", "ExportFunction", templateFileName);
```

You should probably be able to find the equivalent in JS

Not sure if it will help